# Why the process is not running on background?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a **XX** method which takes 2 seconds. I want to do something before it and when **XX** method finishes I want to do another thing.

### The problem is:

It works fine but the problem is everything does when the **XX** method finish , I mean the method which must run before **XX** and  the method which must run after **XX** work togeter after **XX** method finish.

### What I did is:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     beforeXX();
                }
            }); 

XX();//takes 2 seconds   

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     afterXX();
                }
            });
```

**afterXX();** and  **beforeXX();** are both of them are change the view.
(I also tried **AsyncTask** method)

thanks in advance

Comment: can u show your AsyncTask code which is more suitable here.. with PreExecute and PostExecute

Comment: Why didn't the `AsyncTask` work for you?

Comment: I think you might be creating a race condition there, because `beforeXX` may or may not finish before `xx()` is even called, and given the naming - `before` needs to be run completely before `xx` starts.  Then `xx` blocks until you're done.  An `AsyncTask` is definitely a better approach.

Comment: I am so sorry AsyncTask is working , I just do somethings wrong but AsyncTask is working fine

Comment: In this case , I must say asynctask is what you need!

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp can I go through the parameter to **onpreexecute** method not do in background method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Moved from comment*

I think you might be creating a race condition there, because `beforeXX` may or may not finish before `xx()` is even called, and given the naming - `before` needs to be run completely before `xx` starts.  Then `xx` blocks until you're done.  An `AsyncTask` is definitely a better approach.

Take for example:

```
// The three generics here are: 
// 1) What is passed into doInBackground (invoked via .execute())
// 2) onProgressUpdate params (I didn't include that)
// 3) What is passed into onPostExecute
public class DoMyBackendWork extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // do beforeXX(); stuff here, this runs on the UI thread
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... filePaths) {
        // do the xx(); code here.  It will be sequential, such as:
        // data = expensiveSetup();
        // procData = processData(data);
        // expensivePostDataThatCanBeDoneInBackground(procData);
        // return strings...;  This goes to onPostExecute
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // do afterXX(); stuff here, this runs on the UI thread
        // this data comes from the return of doInBackground
    }
    private void expensiveSetup() {}
    private ProcessedData processData(Data data) {}
    private void expensivePostDataThatCanBeDoneInBackground(ProcessedData data) {}
}
```

Then in wherever you are calling that from:

```
DoMyBackendWork dmbw = new DoMyBackendWork(/* add ctor and params if needed */);
dmbw.execute(/* string params */);
```

Comment: But if beforexx() method cost much time or afterxx() may cost much time ? I think call the three methods all in the doinbackground() but in a line maybe better,because that will avoid the ANR ?

Comment: **You shouldn't be doing anything expensive on any UI thread.**  You doing it in `onPreExecute` or your OP (`runOnUiThread`) is about as bad.  Instead, you should do quick UI updates in `onPreExecute/onPostExecute` and everything expensive in the background.  You can add some private methods and call them sequentially in the `doInBackground` method, that isn't a problem and maintains your required ordering but runs them sequentially.

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp - Added an example more relevant to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply run the code in the lines of

```
beforeXX();
XX();
afterXX();
```

?

What you wrote is not guaranteed to be executed in the order that your code is written and in the way you expect, because thread management belongs to the operating system and not to you as a programmer.

The least you can do to solve your problem is to *wait* for the threads beforeXX and afterXX to finish. First thing I'm thinking of is use an Object as a lock and syncrhonize your threads on it. If you don't know how to do that, ask and I'll update my answer.